# Вывод самых больших значений.

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Такая ситуация, есть бд - mysql. В ней допустим табличка znacheniya, а в этой табличке такие столбики: id, name, chislo. В этой же табличке такие значения:

`1 - id, name - Tolya, chislo - 1; 
2 - id, name - Igor, chislo - 5; 
3 - id, name - Pasha, chislo - 3;`

Задача, вывести значения chislo от большего к меньшего на php, Вот так:

```
Igor - 5
Pasha - 3
Tolya - 1
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `znacheniya` ORDER BY `chislo` DESC";
$res = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    echo $row[name].' - '.$row[chislo];
}

// По поводу единственной строки с максимальным значением:

$query = "SELECT * FROM `znacheniya` ORDER BY `chislo` DESC LIMIT 1";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row[name].' - '.$row[chislo];
```

Comment: А если вывести одно самое большое значения?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону **SELECT MAX() ...**

-----------

Кстати, даже при первом варианте запроса, у вас в первой строке результата, будет максимальное значение.

Comment: Не понял, я просто еще нуб в php =)

Comment: > А если вывести одно самое большое значения?

SELECT MAX(`chislo`) FROM znacheniya`

Comment: Спасибо огромное =)